# How can I link image on android phone to database

Tags: android, database, image

Is there some way where I can just link the images from the phone to my sqlite database? At first I thought of storing them in the phone memory in a new database but I am thinking that will blow away the space. Can anyone plzz help.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the pictures? Are they just files? If so, just store the filename to them as a string? If you're talking about the images in Android's media storage, you can just store the Uri to the content provider as a string (i.e. whatever you're using to retrieve it via `MediaStore.Images`).